# The use of "a lot of" in my sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "**a lot of**" at the end of my sentence?

- I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think a lot of.

Or

- I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think a lot.

Answer (score 2):

*a lot* is a quantifying expression that can be used on its own when the context is understood. It's often used to explicitly state what it is quantifying by adding *of* before plural nouns (or uncountable nouns).

First, your sentences need *it is* to be grammatical.

> I think it's a lot.  O
> I think it's a lot of rain. O
> I think a lot of. X
> I think a lot. [this is grammatical but it means 'I do a lot of thinking' or 'I think very often', so *a lot* is modifying the wrong word here]

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think a lot of.

Firstly, the adverb 'lot' here is modifying the verb 'think', and certainly not the noun 'rain' as you intend.

Secondly, this statement is fairly incomplete. *Thinking a lot of (what?).* What are you thinking about? Even if you use such sentence anywhere else, it will be incomprehensible.

As already highlighted in their answer by @kandyman, 'a lot' can stand on its own as a independent expression, describing a whole lot of something. However, you need to specify it explicitly what 'a lot' is about.

> I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think a lot.

This sentence indicates that you do a lot of thinking. To mean what you intend to convey, you can rephrase as:

> I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think **it's a lot**.

Here, "it's" would join the intended phrasing of 'rain' to the quantifier 'a lot'.

> I don't know how many inches of rain we get. I think **it's a lot of it**.

As I mentioned earlier, the preposition would need something to link the quantifier to, which in this case is the 'a lot' getting linked to 'rain'.